# Любопытный или любознательный?

Tags: лексика

**В в XVIII в слово "любознательный" встречается редко, а слово "любопытный" обычно имеет положительное значение**, например: "Крекшин Петр ― комиссар капитанского чина, человек **любопытный и тщательный** в собирании российских древностей и редкостей. [Н. И. Новиков. (1772)]. Также Пушкин писал: "Как жаль, что Грибоедов не оставил своих записок! Написать его биографию было бы делом его друзей; но замечательные люди исчезают у нас, не оставляя по себе следов. **Мы ленивы и нелюбопытны**...»

В. Даль  в своем словаре  (1861—1868) приводит значения обоих слов: **любознание  ― дельное любопытство**, любовь к наукам, к познаниям, желание поучаться. Любопытный ― тот,  кто любит допытываться, дознаваться всего **без надобности и пользы**.

**Когда и почему любопытство приобрело негативный оттенок значения?** "Любопытный скиф" у Пушкина ― это похвала или порицание?  И правильно ли толкуется это выражение в школьных разборах стихотворения, например: "Отметив, что за границей Юсупов пробовал пополнять свой умственный багаж беседами с такими умами, как Дидро, Пушкин тотчас же оговаривает, что в основе этого лежало **лишь простое любопытство**".

**И зачем это в лейденском университете Юсупов прослушал** курсы права, философии, политической истории, естественной истории; занимался ботаникой, физикой, химией, математикой, анатомией. Кроме того, в учебную программу князя входили — латынь, древнегреческий, итальянский, английский языки, а также занятия живописью и музыкой. Сам он писал: "Я продолжаю изучать химию у Брандта… Зимой я буду посещать занятия по анатомии Стантифора… "

**Всё это никчемное любопытство?** Наверное, вот и  современные дети говорят: "Зачем мне эта химия?" ― и идут учиться в вуз на тренера по танцам. Хорошая профессия... **Возможно, они не любопытны отчасти потому,  что в школе именно так разбирали стихотворение Пушкина "К вельможе".**

Comment: Или «в 18-м в., или в XVIII в.: http://ktvd.ru/narascvhenia-chislitilnyh/.

Comment: @shampar Для годов и веков наращение обычно не употребляется, если есть слово век или год (или сокращение от них).

Comment: Sibylla поправила, правда с опечатками, но и так хорошо. Обычность, как Вы выразились, в удобстве процесса чтения проявляется, а не писания. Пишет один, а недоумевают многие. Да ещё что интересно: не она это писала, но она скопировала.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**"Когда и почему любопытство приобрело негативный оттенок значения?"** - во второй половине XX века, почему - неясно.

В словаре Ушакова на первом месте стоит нейтральное значение: "**1. стремление, страсть узнать в подробностях что-нибудь новое, вновь появившееся, услышанное**. Удовлетворить чье-н. любопытство. Возбудить любопытство. Проявлять любопытство", и только на втором "2. Неоправдываемое разумными целями стремление знать, видеть, слышать всё, что окружает человека в быту, вплоть до мелких, несущественных подробностей".

В Малом академическом словаре: "**Стремление узнать, услышать что-л. во всех, даже несущественных, подробностях**" - как бы уже с намёком на что-то нехорошее.

У Ожегова-Шведовой уже на первом месте видим: "**1. Мелочный интерес ко всяким, даже несущественным подробностям**", а всё хорошее переместилось на второе место: "2. Стремление узнать, увидеть что-н. новое, проявление интереса к чему-н."

Но вы не расстраивайтесь, похоже, что эта тенденция пошла на убыль: в более позднем толковом словаре Ефремовой (2000 г.) видим совершенно нейтральное: "**Стремление узнать что-либо во всех подробностях; проявление интереса к кому-либо или к чему-либо**".

Учёные тоже склонны к нейтралитету (или даже к положительной оценке): "Любопытство - Предположительно — **врожденная склонность организмов искать новое в своем окружении**" (Большая психологическая энциклопедия, 2000 год, кажется, а впрочем, неважно).

**Дополнение**

Как правильно напомнила Sibylla, вопрос начался с Даля: в этом словаре XIX века "любопытный - кто любит допытываться, дознаваться всего без надобности и пользы" (в статье "Любить"), то есть оттенок отрицательный, и значения второго (нейтрального) нет.

Оказывается, существует словарь и более раннего периода русского языка:

Словарь русского языка XVIII века / АН СССР. Ин-т рус. яз.; Гл. ред.: Ю. С. Сорокин. — Л.: Наука. Ленингр. отд-ние, 1984—1991. — Вып. 1—6; СПб.: Наука. С.-Петерб. отд-ние, 1992—... — Вып. 7—..

В этом словаре на первом месте стоит значение "**Любознательность, пытливость ума; интерес к чему-л.**", на втором: "**Сильное (обычно неуместное) желание что-л. узнать, увидеть и т. п.**". Там достаточно много примеров из текстов XVIII века: [ЛЮБОПЫ́ТСТВО | feb-web.ru](http://feb-web.ru/feb/sl18/slov-abc/12/slc01602.htm?cmd=2&istext=1)

Comment: Спасибо, интересно. Вот только Даль в своем словаре уже противопоставляет  любопытство и любознательность, а  это только середина XIX века.  Что-то в обществе наметилось еще тогда.

Comment: Видимо, "величина отрицательного оттенка" у слова "любопытство" колеблется: от Даля - к Ушакову - к Ожегову - к Ефремовой... А что было раньше Даля, по словарям трудно определить, надо изучать множество разных текстов.

Comment: Любопытство погубило кошку. Любопытство - не порок, но большое свинство. И наконец... "Мы любознательны, но не любопытны" (из Стругацких)

Answer (score 2):

> Когда и почему любопытство приобрело негативный оттенок значения? Я что-то не ощущаю.

А если Даля отбросить, есть основания полагать, что приобрело?
Даль - это всего лишь Даль, человек не имевший филологического образования. он и накосячить мог. К тому же постановка вопроса о "надобности и пользе" несколько нафталином отдает. Трактовка какая-то меркантильная. Пушкин стихи про Керн писал - с надобностью-пользой? Мое мнение, любопытсво - синоним любознательности, возможно более широкий по значению, но не более. Противопоставлять их я бы не стал. Ни а Пушкинскую эпоху, на в Далевскую, ни в современную.

> "Любопытный скиф" у Пушкина ― это похвала или порицание?

Ни то, ни другое. Это нейтральная харатеристика. Но если уж ребром ставить вопрос, то конечно, ближе к положительной.

> Пушкин тотчас же оговаривает, что в основе этого лежало лишь простое 
>   любопытство

Замечание-то верное, но что из него следует? Я так понимаю, что Юсупов проявлял простой интерес, не связанный с какими-то насущными потребностями или выгодами. С таким же успехом здесь можно сказать "простая любознательность". Я не собираюсь давать историческую или литературную оценку высказыванию, не моя тема, но по части значения слова - понимаю так.

> Всё это никчемное любопытство...

Откуда эта цитата? Слишком уж на многое претендует. Но одно понятно, если бы любопытство само по себе носило негативную окраску, "никчемное" было бы излишним.

Comment: ПРОСТОЕ ЛЮБОПЫТСТВО  сделало Юсупова собирателем крупнейшей художественной коллекции. А вот что говорится об усадьбе Архангельское: "Вплоть до начала ХХ века Архангельское выполняло неофициальную роль царской подмосковной резиденции. Романовы сколько ни пытались, но на протяжении всего 19-го век так и не смогли обустроить для себя официальную резиденцию вблизи древней столицы, как это полагалось по этикету. Дворец в Коломенском сломали, дворец в Царицыне так и не отделали. «Петровский замок» или дворец в Нескучном на роль парадной резиденции явно «не тянули».

Comment: А вот как вели себя люди, которые ничего не изучали из простого любопытства. Библиотеку Юсуповых сожгли на площади местные крестьяне.  Местной учительнице удалось достать дневник Юсупова. Где же он теперь?!«В войну искурили», — был ответ». "Эти бывшие революционно настроенные гимназисточки и Рафаэля бы на портянки пустили, попадись он им".

Comment: @Sibylla Вы не могли бы формулировать вопросы или замечание конкретнее? Что в моем ответе вас не устроило? И откуда цитата?

Comment: Мне  не нравится, что в школьных разборах стихотворения пренебрежительно оценивается интерес Юсупова к разнообразным наукам, обозначается  как простое любопытство.  Мне не нравится, что  современная молодежь очень прагматична и   имеет узкий кругозор, связанный в основном с будущей профессией.  И такое отсутствие  интересов поддерживается школьной практикой (одно натаскивание на ЕГЭ чего стоит). А вас это вроде бы всё устраивает, но это ваше мнение. Я же привожу примеры того, какие плоды приносит простое любопытство и его отсутствие. http://www.universalinternetlibrary.ru/book/22490/ogl.shtml

Comment: *Мне не нравится, что в школьных разборах стихотворения пренебрежительно оценивается интерес Юсупова к разнообразным наукам* - ну а я-то чем могу Вам помочь?

Comment: Ну морально поддержать, сказать, что это неправильно.  В любом случае спасибо за внимание к вопросу.

Answer (score 1):

Любознательность – потешить "высокий" ум (как устроена Вселенная). Без надобности и пользы!

Любопытство – потешить "низкий" ум (кого сегодня сосед Кирилл Андреевич привел к себе домой). Тоже без надобности и пользы, но это можно обсудить с соседкой Нюркой!

Раньше люди были цельные, и им всем хватало одного слова: аристократы под этим словом всегда понимали первое, а подлые людишки – второе. Совсем не так теперь: аристократов не осталось, остались только эрудиты и прочие "интеллектуалы", а им хочется и о высоком поговорить, и в замочную скважину иногда глянуть. Понадобилось два слова, и вот вам пожалуйста.

Comment: "Любопытный и тщательный", "мы ленивы и нелюбопытны" - здесь, как мне кажется, речь идет о ПОЛЕЗНОМ качестве. Только вот о каком? Может быть, это слово имело какое-то другое значение и как эти выражения звучали бы в наше время?

Comment: Ясно, что в значении "любознательный".

Comment: Вы же пишите, что "без надобности и пользы". Любознательность - нужное, полезное качество (тогда и сейчас)?

Comment: Ага, считается нужным и полезным, как чтение книг, например. Но вспомним Оскара Уайльда: "всякое искусство совершенно бесполезно". Вот в этом смысле любознательность – она тоже "без надобности и пользы". Ну какая польза знать, что писали в берестяных грамотах или что такое бозон Хиггса?

Comment: Niemand, про  бозон тоже можно посплетничать в определённой компании))

Answer (score 1):

Старо-слав. *Любезновмещати* = с усердием внимать, как и *Любезно* = усердно, понемногу, умеренно, по любви, ревностно и т.п. говорят о накоплении знаний человеком «всерьёз и надолго», т.е. как положено, что и отражается в слове *любознательность*.

Питать тягу к знанию — впитывать, вкушать — очевидно, совсем не то, что *любопытствовать* = *любить+пытать* (в значении *с удовольствием задавать вопросы*; польск. *пытаць* = спрашивать). Разница настолько глубока, что дополнения в виде определений типа *просто* (любопытствовать) или *никчёмное* (любопытство) скорее смягчают её, чем подчёркивают.

Не всегда и не везде любопытный выглядит поверхностным. Человеку маленькому, только открывшему мир, такое определение вполне к лицу.